# Fixing MySQL Error 1064

Tags: mysql

```
ALTER TABLE  `The Watch Desk Articles Index` ADD  `Subject` VARCHAR CHARACTER SET utf8                 
COLLATE utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL AFTER `none` ,
ADD FULLTEXT (

`Subject`
)


#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE  
utf8_general_mysql500_ci NOT NULL AFTER `none`,  ADD ' at line 1
```

What is this error asking me to change? I'm using phpMyAdmin to construct the table column with selection boxes and I keep receiving this error.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, you have to specify the size of your varchar field, for example to allow up to 255 characters:

```
 ALTER TABLE  `The Watch Desk Articles Index` ADD  `Subject` VARCHAR(255) 
     CHARACTER SET  ...rest of stuff here...
```